# Error using while loop with mysqli_fetch_assoc()

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop

I have created a function name `dispcategories()` and inside the function i have created some code to display `category_title` and others things but I am getting this Error

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in ....... on line 7

and this is the code in function.php

```
function dispcategories() {
    include ('dbconn.php');

    $select = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM categories");

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select)) {
        echo "<table class='category-table'>";
        echo "<tr><td class='main-category' colspan='2'>".$row['category_title']."</td></tr>";
        dispsubcategories($row['cat_id']);
        echo "</table>";
    }
}
```

and in index.php

```
<div class="content">
    <?php dispcategories(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Is your misspelling of `catergories` a factor?

Comment: Your query failed. Use error reporting to know why. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Sorry, small typo @neokio but it actually correct in my main code

Comment: Try SQL like this "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE 1"

Comment: but shows no error @user3783243

Comment: sorry but i still shows the error @RajeshPaudel

Comment: @RajeshPaudel How would that ever help?

Comment: @KarmaAkabane What does `var_dump($select)` give you

Comment: no error  @user3783243

Comment: @KarmaAkabane You said that. What does the `var_dump` return?

Comment: Include the results from var_dump($select) if that doesn't work try using mysqli_fetch_array() once again if that doesn't work try to include connection once again in the code later refactor it and if nothing woks try restarting your local server.

Comment: can you tell me more detailed. i am actually very new to PHP @RajeshPaudel

Comment: Edit your question and include the result that var_dump($select) gives you as mention by @user3783243 which should give you what your connection is getting. For the sake of simplicity in including result you can use mysqli_fetch_array($select) if both are giving nothing then try including the connection variable in your function which you can later refactor.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select)) {
```

to

```
while ($row = $select->fetch_assoc()){
```

Comment: why he should change it?